# The closure of the set of linear combinations

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces

The vector space generated by a subset $A$ of a normed space X is the set of finite linear combinations of its elements, and will be denoted by $Lin(A)$.
$$Lin(A)=\{\sum^{n}_{j=1}\lambda_{j} a_{j}: \lambda_{j} \in \mathbb{K}, a_{j} \in A, n\in \mathbb{N}\}.$$

**Show that $\overline{Lin(A)}$ is the smallest closed subspace containing $A$.**

What I thought: we need to show that $\overline{Lin(A)}$ is the intersection of all closed subspaces containing $A$.

Remembering that  : $x \in \overline{Lin(A)}$ if and only if there is a sequence $(x_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ in $Lin(A)$ such that $x_{n}\to x$.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Which topology are you taking in $A$?

Comment: You should note in the question that you assume $X$ is a normed space (and not just a vector space), otherwise the question doesn't make much sense. Anyway, try to show that the closure is also a subspace of $X$, from there it will be easy to finish.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos norm-induced topology.

Comment: @Mark I already showed that for any $S$ vector subspace of $X$, the $\overline{S}$ is a vector subspace of $X$. I did it by showing that: $0\in \overline{S}$ and $x+\lambda y \in \overline{S}$, for all $x,y \in \overline{S}$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{K}$.  **How does it help?**

Comment: @User Well, now you know $\overline{Lin(A)}$ is one of the subspaces which appear in the intersection you defined, and so it contains the intersection. On the other hand, every subspace in the intersection is a closed set containing $Lin(A)$, and so it must contain the closure $\overline{Lin(A)}$ as well. So the intersection also contains $\overline{Lin(A)}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ be a closed vector subspace of $X$ such that $C\supset A$. The goal is to prove that $C\subset\overline{\operatorname{Lin}(A)}$. Since $C\supset A$ and $C$ is vector space, $C\supset\operatorname{Lin}(A)$. Therefore, $\overline C\supset\overline{\operatorname{Lin}(A)}$. But $C$ is closed, and so$$C=\overline C\supset\overline{\operatorname{Lin}(A)}.$$